# Exporting animated materials to Unity

Tags: animation, node-editor, unity

I'm using Blender 2.8.2 with the Evee renderer.  I have a simple object, with an animated material.  Is there a way to export the object for use in Unity with the animated material?
I've tried the GLTF exporter but it did not bring across the animated materials.

THe screen shot here shows the rendered material, the animation key frames and the nodes.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

UV animation isn't supported by any contemporary 3D file format. It's still possible through a few ugly methods, though.

- Use Unity's animation editor to animate the UVs directly inside of Unity. This is easy but not exportable.
- 1. Add a bone and drive the UVs through the bones position, and animate that instead.
  2. Make a script that does the same in Unity.
  3. Export the animation and play that instead.

Make sure the way you drive UVs in Blender and in Unity are identical. If you're using the UV Project modifier you'll have to replicate that exact functionality in Unity as well.  This sorta works but is clunky so I don't really recommend it.

Answer (score 0):

Reference: https://forum.unity.com/threads/can-blender-2-8-eevee-shaders-still-be-used-with-unity.645271/

Asking a Unity3D game developer about your question brought me to the conclusion that you can't actually export "animated materials" from Blender to Unity unless you recreate the shader IN Unity/ More info in the link i gave you.

Comment: Could you give reasons for it?

Comment: Thanks for the link.  I'll look at it and hopefully it will be at least in shouting distance of my current knowledge/skill level.